# Como consumir un microservicio (net core) desde una app WinForm en .net framework

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

Estoy tratando de consumir un microservicio hecho en .NET core que retorna un json, desde una aplicación WinForm en .NET Framework, debe ser sencillo pero las opciones de importar un servicio desde Visual Studio no me dejan.. 
Alguna idea?

Comment: Que tipo de servicio es? si es simplemente un servicio web, no tenes que incluirlo, solo tenes que hacer la llamada web correspondiente...

Comment: Estoy acostumbrado a consumir ws tipo soap, en los que se tiene un wsdl, pero este es solo una url que retorna un json..

Comment: Por favor, las respuestas van en el campo respuesta, no como edicion a la pregunta.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Hola, si estas usando APIs de netCore podes agregar Swagger al API y luego desde VS importar el archivo de documentacion que genera como cualquier WS. Necesitamos que nos cuentes un poco mas como estas haciendo... tb si la app de winforms esta hecha con una version vieja de VS/Net Framework talvez se deba hacer de otra forma.

Comment: Hola ya solucione mi inconveniente, era solo usar HttpClient y claro parsear la respuesta del servicio como json.. por alguna razón típica de stackover.. me borraron la respuesta que había colocado... asi que dejo esto como comentario para que no lo borren!!

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Answer (score 0):

Yo te aconsejo que mires documentación de como consumir API-REST en .NET, concretamente lee sobre los objetos HttpClient y HttpClientFactory